# Reproductor de videos Embedded de YouTube dice "No disponible" en ocasiones - Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, youtube

Estoy implementando un reproductor de videos de `YouTube` en la app con el uso de un `WebView` y configurandolo para que muestre el video de tipo `Embedded` (solo el video y no la pagina web del video en YouTube), sin embargo solo me funciona con algunos videos si y con otros no. (Ya revise que pudieran utilizarse como embedded).

**El error (cuando lo da) lo muestra asi:**

[image: Error]

El metodo para modificar el URL del video de Reproductor web a Embedded es el siguiente:

```
string VideoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YzGOq42zLk";
                        VideoURL = VideoURL.Replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
                        VideoURL = (VideoURL + "?feature=oembed").ToString();
```

Metodo de Reproducir video es:

```
string EmbededAdress = "<iframe width = \"400\" height = \"225\" src = \"" + DigiteURL +"\" " +
                    "title \"SpoiledBuff - YouTube\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; " +
                    "picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>>";
                
                string mimeType = "text/html";
                string encoding = "UTF-8";
                string UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36";

                FeedViewHolder hh = VarGlobal.xxholder as FeedViewHolder;

                hh.webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = (true);
                hh.webView.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = (false);
                hh.webView.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
                hh.webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                hh.webView.Settings.UserAgentString = UserAgent;
                hh.webView.Settings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;

                hh.webView.SetWebChromeClient((new WebChromeClient()));
                hh.webView.SetWebViewClient((new WebViewClient()));

                hh.webView.LoadUrl(EmbededAdress);
                hh.webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl: "", EmbededAdress, mimeType, encoding, historyUrl: "");
```

**¿Alguna idea de como corregir esto para poder mostrar el video en la app?**

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que el video tiene restricciòn para ser reproducido.

Hay muchas razones por las que se puede restringir la reproducción de video. El usuario puede estar en un país donde el video está bloqueado o el propietario del contenido del video puede haber decidido bloquear el acceso al video desde todas las aplicaciones móviles.

**este puede ser bloqueado por derechos de autor o el mismos propietario que subio el video puede configurar restricciones para que este no sea reproducido en determinado paìs, en un reproductor embebido, o incluso en un dispositivo mòvil!**

Revisa:

[**Gestionar las restricciones de los vídeos**](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9668091?hl=es)

[**Consultar las restricciones de tus vídeos en la aplicación YouTube Studio**](https://support.google.com/youtubecreatorstudio/answer/6357492)

Te sugiero usar el [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) para evitar la restricciòn del reproductor embebido.

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Youtube-API

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder tan detalladamente. Estaba revisando este video y ya que tu has usado la API quería consultarte lo siguiente: ¿Al usar la API puedo mostrar el video en mi app de tal forma que solo se vea el recuadro del video, o el resultado se vera como si estuviera en la app de YouTube como en esta foto? -- https://ibb.co/cDkVyKr -- Te lo pregunto porque un resultado que parezca como que si es YouTube no me sirve. Necesito poder tener solo un rectangulo pequeño en una pantalla de la app y que ahi se reproduzca el video como en este foto: -- https://ibb.co/n7XtyKj --